# Is it more efficient to load data to a listview from SQLite or create listviews from an array?

Tags: android

Hey guys I was just wondering about some efficiency issues. I am creating an app for android that has a few listviews, some listviews have 50+ items. Basically click one item on one listview will open up another listview that displays more options and so forth.

My question is right now I have these listviews populated from arrays but would it be more efficient to create a database and pull data to populate these listviews?

If this question has been asked already I apologize I have searched but have not found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Beside of choosing between arrays or sql as datasource, is important to analyze the complexity of your view; sometimes is important "*load views on demand*" you may want consider this best-practices for optimization of your app: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html and this https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Best.-

Comment: Thanks I will def check those links out

Answer (score 0):

If list data is not dynamic, I feel string arrays are best otherwise database is best option. database calls are always costly in terms of time/resources.

Comment: Ya, the data is not dynamic. Its basically list courses, then the subject and classes for each course, then professors who teach them

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data, if your data doesn't change , you can define them in xml file under ./value/. And sqlite just like other database, and it cost another I/O operations and it will reduce efficiency. But I think it doesn't cost too much in an android app.